# Bad file descriptor ERROR during apk update in Docker container... Why?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, devops, alpine-linux

After running:

```
docker network rm $NETNAME
docker network create --driver bridge $NETNAME --subnet "${SUBNET}0/24"
docker run --name $NODENAME -it --net $NETNAME --ip 192.168.0.2 --volume --detach $IMGNAME
```

inside the container, as root, I run `apk udpdate`:

```
# apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main: Bad file descriptor
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.70c88391.tar.gz: Bad file descriptor
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community: Bad file descriptor
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.5022a8a2.tar.gz: Bad file descriptor
2 errors; 33 distinct packages available
```

... and hit the `Bad file descriptor` error.

There a number of other folks that have encountered the same error:

[CDN seems to be down and cannot get mirrors working #280](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/280)

[Repository problem? #279](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/279)

Suggestions on how to resolve this range from:

> "It's a DNS lookup error.  Just add google DNS servers (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) to your Docker host's deamon config file."

... to ...

> "Add the following to your Dockerfile:"
>
> `RUN echo http://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/alpine/v3.5/main >
>   /etc/apk/repositories; \
>       echo http://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/alpine/v3.5/community >> /etc/apk/repositories`

(Which you should *NOT* do.  Never add packages from non-official sources.)

**Solution**

The solution was easy enough.  Add these 2 lines to your RUN command:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/apk && \
mkdir /var/cache/apk && \
```

In Dockerfile ...

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache bash \
    git \
    make \
    clang \
    g++ \
    go && \
    mkdir -p $REPO && \
    mkdir -p $GODIR/src && \
    rm -rf /usr/share/man && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk && \
    mkdir /var/cache/apk && \
    apk del git clang
```

Adding commands to delete and recreate the `/var/cache/apk` directory feels like a hack.

My hack works, but what is the root cause of this error and who should fix it?

Comment: This surely is a pesky bug.

Answer (score 2):

`--no-cache` option allows to not cache the index locally.
That is helpful in keeping the container small.

Also, it is equivalent to  `apk update` at the top and `rm -rf /var/cache/apk/` in the end.

So you can try to use it this way:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache bash \
    git \
    make \
    clang \
    g++ \
    go && \
    mkdir -p $REPO && \
    mkdir -p $GODIR/src && \
    rm -rf /usr/share/man && \
    apk del git clang
```